# Parsley.js message won't display in custom error container

Tags: jquery, html, validation, parsley.js

I'm trying to place a custom Parsley.js error message into a custom container but the message appears in the standard `<ul id="parsley-40824446517889035" class="parsley-error-list">` element instead.  Here's my simple test:

```
<form parsley-validate novalidate>
<input type="text" id="parsley-minlength" parsley-minlength="6" placeholder="minlength = 6" parsley-error-message="Please enter a valid value" parlsey-error-container="#msgspan" required="required" />
<span id="msgspan"></span>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="mytestbutton" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

The example in the Parsley documentation indicates that the element should be referenced like this:

```
parsley-error-container="ul#myproperlabel li.someclass"
```

I'm unclear as to what #myproperlabel and someclass are referring to.  Do I need to add a ul instead of a span element to my HTML with a someclass name?

I see examples on SO of referencing the 'elem' jQuery function but am unclear if that post allows me to set the message to my custom span or if it only places the message outside the parent element.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You have a typo, it is `parsley-error-container="#msgspan"` and not `parlsey-error-container="#msgspan"` ;)

Answer (score 1):

In the new version (2.0), you have to use `data-parsley-errors-container="#myid"` to show the error message